# Need a help with vertical alignment of input fields

Tags: css

I need a help with a vertical alignment of the input fields. I want the text input boxes to be aligned with each other. Please take a look: http://www.carteretcountyforeclosures.com/foreclosures/

This website is a WordPress site. This  search form is in the IDX Plugin. This misalignment is happening only in this particular WP Theme. If I change the theme everything looks great. So I know there is something wrong with this style.css. Here’s the link http://www.carteretcountyforeclosures.com/files/style.css

Could you please help? I’ve spend so much time for searching for resolution of this and nothing seems to work for me. 
Thank you in advance for your time and effort.

Comment: This is a CSS problem, not a WordPress problem. Migrating to Stack Overflow where it will be on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

The styling is a messy mix of floats and relative positioning. It would probably be faster to redesign the layout using a table than to debug the CSS code.

Answer (score 0):

What browser are you using? I took a look at this in IE8 & FF10 and everything lines up except the "Property Type" dropdown. A quick look at your code shows `<h1 style='color:#FFFFFF;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;'></h1>` right above the label for the dropdown, which could be pushing it down a few pixels. The classes in the divs surrounding that (`<div class='right'>`,`class='property-type'`, and `class='label'`) are not defined in your css. Try adding some style attributes (like margin or padding) for one or more of these classes, or delete the empty h1 tag to help bring this field into vertical alignment with the location field.